# How do i retrieve each string character in c

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers

```
for(x=0;x<Title_Size;x++){
    current_char = *(Title+x);//retrieve each character of Title array
    for(j=x;j<Title_Size;j++){
        if(current_char == *(Title+j+1)){
            //increment current_char_cnt
            current_char_cnt++;
        }//End If
    }
 }
```

In the above code my interest is in this line: `current_char = *(Title+x);`
Title is a word like say: duel gotten from an array of several words like:

```
char *SearchTitle[6] = {"uuel","dule","speed","spede","deul","cars"};
```

Title is originally passed as a parameter in this function call:

```
HMKey = Compute_HashMapKey_for_each_title (SearchTitle[x]);
```

And then this is how i declared it in the function header or prototype:

```
char Compute_HashMapKey_for_each_title (char title[])
```

Then another function which is called in Compute_HashMapKey_for_each_title is passed Title like this:

```
Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title(title);
```

And then of course the line of code where i am having issues is in this particular function definition:

```
Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title
```

i.e:

```
void Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title(char Title[]){
int Title_Size;
Title_Size = (sizeof(Title) - 4)/sizeof(Title[0]);//get size of Title
int x,j;
//Initialize current_char to char for character comparison in title_array
char current_char;
//Initialize current_char_cnt to 0
int current_char_cnt = 1;
char Alphabets[][1] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
//Foreach character in title array, calculate individual character frequency here
for(x=0;x<Title_Size;x++){
    current_char = *(Title+x);//retrieve each character of Title array
    for(j=x;j<Title_Size;j++){
        if(current_char == *(Title+j+1)){
            //increment current_char_cnt
            current_char_cnt++;
        }//End If
    }
    /*Insert current_char_cnt in title_char_cnt_array against index - index no. represents position of char in alphabetical order*/
    if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[0]) == 0)
        if(title_char_cnt_array[0] == 0)//if no previous value inserted, then insert
            title_char_cnt_array[0] = current_char_cnt;
    else if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[1]) == 0)
        if(title_char_cnt_array[1] == 0)
            title_char_cnt_array[1] = current_char_cnt;
    else if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[2]) == 0)
        if(title_char_cnt_array[2] == 0)
            title_char_cnt_array[2] = current_char_cnt;
    else if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[3]) == 0)
        if(title_char_cnt_array[3] == 0)
            title_char_cnt_array[3] = current_char_cnt;
    else if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[4]) == 0)
        if(title_char_cnt_array[4] == 0)
            title_char_cnt_array[4] = current_char_cnt;
}//End For
}
```

Now the code fails once it gets to where i am comparing current_char to Alphabets[0] to see if characters are same or not.

i.e from here:

```
if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[0]) == 0)
```

Even the debugger goes off here without any useful information. I believe i have do something wrong here.

Using the debugger, current_char has the value 101'd' as its first character for a word like: duel while Alphabets[0] shows: "a"

I don't have an idea what the issue is but the debugger log in CodeBlock shows this:

> In strcmp () (C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll)
> #1  0x0000000000401688 in Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title (Title=0x405000 "uuel") at C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53
> C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53:2227:beg:0x401688
> At C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53
> In strcmp () (C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll)
> #1  0x0000000000401688 in Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title (Title=0x405000 "uuel") at C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53
> C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53:2227:beg:0x401688
> At C:\Users\HP\Documents\MyFirstCPrj\MyFirstC\Group Similar Titles\main.c:53

And of course this are my header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Please can you kindly show me what the problem is?

Comment: Where are you seeing `101'd'`?  The contents of the array are characters and `current_char` has to contain a single character.  So I suspect you are seeing the `101'd'` in the debugger's watch window and assuming that this is literally what the variable contains.  `101` is the numeric value of `d` and so the debugger is just showing you both - but there is no way that `current_char` actually contains both.  If you print `current_char` as a character it will display `d` and if you print it as a number you will see `101` because it is the same data interpreted two different ways.

Comment: You use `current_char = *(Title+x);` — it's simpler and easier to understand if you write `current_char = Title[x];`, and better idiomatic C, too.

Comment: The code shown for `Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title()` had better not compile — it is missing declarations for local variables `x`, `current_char`, `j`.  It uses too many global variables too — assuming `Title_Size` and `current_char_cnt` are global variables rather than undeclared local variables.  Presenting non-compilable code doesn't endear your question to those who might help.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses).

Comment: @Jerry Your point clarifies the issue a bit. Its true that i am assuming that current_char has the value 101'd' instead of d because truly i used the debugger to check the value. With that said, i have edited the question to show you where the issue that made me assume that current_char has the value 101'd' instead of d. Please kindly check and help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In strcmp you are trying to compair a character to a string

```
//Initialize current_char to char for character comparison in title_array
char current_char;

...

if(strcmp(current_char, Alphabets[0]) == 0)
```

**man strcmp**

int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

Answer (score 0):

This is a common C beginner error:

```
void Get_Individual_Character_Frequency_For_Each_Title(char Title[]){
    int Title_Size;
    Title_Size = (sizeof(Title) - 4)/sizeof(Title[0]);//get size of Title
```

When you pass an array to a function, it *decays* to a pointer. That means that `sizeof(Title)` **is** `sizeof(char *)` in the function, which is not what you want. You must either use `strlen` if the string is properly null terminater (`Title_Size = strlen(Title);